# Использование apply в Pandas

Tags: python, функции, pandas, dataframe, lambda

Почему использование анонимной функции lambda в указанном ниже случае приводит к работоспособности кода?

Так работает:

```
X.apply(lambda vx: ax(t_1, t_2, vx), axis=1)
```

Так не работает:

```
def ax(t1, t2, X):
     return   (-t1 * X[1] - t2 * X[2])

X.apply(ax(t_1, t_2, X), axis=1)
```

`t_1` и `t_2` - некоторые числа

`X` - dataset, числа, в котором два столбца и N строк

Comment: Поясните что такое X, что должна делать функция, какие параметры она принимает. Python динамически типы обрабатывает. Из-за этого может быть проблема.

Comment: Что значит не работоспособности кода? Какая ошибка? и Как Вы вызываете функцию у переменной, которая еще не инициализирована? Как тогда она вообще работает, если X не существует?

Comment: X это DataSet  состоящий из двух колонок и 200 строк. t1 и  t2 это два числа. 
Для каждой строки (i) должно быть вычислено 
X[1][i]*t1-X[2][i]*t2

Comment: @ayv2004, вы можете привести текст ошибки?

Comment: В одном случае вы передаёте *функцию* (lambda), в другом случае вы передаёте *результат* вызова функции. Если func это функция, то func() вызывает эту функцию в Питоне.

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете решить данную проблему немного изменив функцию:

```
In [11]: def ax(row, t1, t2):
    ...:     return (-t1 * row['x'] - t2 * row['y'])
    ...:

In [12]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5, size=(5, 2)), columns=list('xy'))

In [13]: df
Out[13]:
   x  y
0  4  2
1  1  0
2  4  4
3  2  3
4  3  2
```

и вызов этой функции в `DF.apply()`:

```
In [15]: df.apply(ax, args=(2,3), axis=1)
Out[15]:
0   -14
1    -2
2   -20
3   -13
4   -12
dtype: int64
```

Обратите внимание на следующие моменты:

1. в качестве аргумента `func` мы указываем только имя функции, без аргументов
2. для `axis=1` первым аргументом при вызове функции `func` будет передаваться строка DataFrame как Pandas.Series
3. при помощи аргумента `args=()` мы можем передать дополнительные позиционные (не именованные) аргументы в функцию `func`. Первым аргументом будет Pandas.Series со значениями соответствующими значениям текущей строки

---

Использование `.apply(...)` и особенно `.apply(..., axis=1)` в Pandas не приветствуется (это медленная и не эффективная операция) и должно быть использовано только в том случае, когда невозможно найти векторизированное (vectorized) решение.

В вашем случае можно написать функцию, работающую с векторами (столбцами).

Пример DataFrame:

```
In [21]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 2)), columns=list('xy'))

In [22]: df
Out[22]:
   x  y
0  4  2
1  7  2
2  9  7
3  0  6
4  2  8
5  1  0
6  3  3
7  1  2
8  8  5
9  8  1
```

Функция работающая с веторами:

```
In [23]: def ax(t1, t2, x, y):
    ...:      return   (-t1 * x - t2 * y)
    ...:
```

Пример использования:

```
In [24]: ax(2, 3, df['x'], df['y'])
Out[24]:
0   -14
1   -20
2   -39
3   -18
4   -28
5    -2
6   -15
7    -8
8   -31
9   -19
dtype: int32
```

Comment: Благодарю все понятно и  встало на свои места!!!!!!!!

Comment: @ayv2004, [чтобы поблагодарить авторов ответов, проголосуйте за их ответы и отметьте лучший (на ваш взгляд) ответ как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Потому что вы определяете функцию позже её использования. Соответственно, в момент, когда вы пытаетесь делать `apply`, этой функции ещё не существует.

Comment: Пардон это в вопросе так приведено. В реальной программе сначала определение потом использование. Это отсеиваем.

Answer (score 1):

Предполагаю следующее:

```
X.apply(lambda vx: ax(t_1, t_2, vx), axis=1)
```

так вызывается функция к каждой строке - как Вам и надо.

```
X.apply(ax(t_1, t_2, X), axis=1)
```

так Вы пытаетесь вызвать функцию и применить ее к dataset.
Соответсвенно в X[1] попадает целый столбец. Полагаю python просто не может понять, что с этим делать. Ибо из коробки без импортов работать с векторами он не умеет.